# How to disable nginx user input buffer?

Tags: nginx, php

I am using nginx and php-fpm. Nginx always buffer user input before send it to php-fpm. Example code:

```
<?php 
     exit("do not input anything");

     // Do something, it's not important because the script was stopped
     $handle = fopen('php://input','r');
     while (!feof($handle)) { 
             fread($handle,1024);
    }
     fclose($handle);
?>
```

---

I use put method to send data from client
If client send a file, the connection is not closed immediately, 
It waits for the request complete !

---

The code works perfect for apache but nginx :(

---

Is there solution for this problem ? Thanks !